# Can't establish a connection NodeJS

Tags: node.js, networking, server

I am a novice at networking, I have a NodeJS server running with `server.listen(3000, '10.0.0.7');` and have forwarded port 3000 with the internal IP address of my server being 10.0.0.7. I can connect from another machine on my network by putting in the browser: 10.0.0.7:3000. It is my understanding that my external IP address should connect me to the router which should then forward me to the server I have set up on 3000.

Am I missing something important? Because I am unable to connect via the external IP address.

Also please note that my firewall is disabled.

Comment: what do you mean by external ip addess in this context

Comment: The one that whatsmyip.org tells me, might've been the wrong term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am neither a network expert so excuse me if I use any incorrect terms. In my understanding, you are right about the current configuration, however you are missing the last step. By default, your router makes your LAN unreachable from a so called “external ip”. Just for the definition: external ip in this case is every ip that is not in your LAN. Imagine if your router would allow any communication without you explicitly giving permission. Every open port on your LAN would be available for the network that your router connects to. That is definitely not desirable.

Lets look at it with an example, quoted from [this article](https://medium.com/botfuel/how-to-expose-a-local-development-server-to-the-internet-c31532d741cc):

- your router has an ip of: `5.6.7.8` if you access it from outer network (internet)
- your router has an ip of: `192.168.1.1` if you access it from your LAN
- your laptop is in your LAN and has an ip address of `192.168.1.10` and you want to expose port `3000` from your laptop to the outer network (internet)

You have 2 options:

- You can expose the port via the configuration of the router (e.g.: you map `5.6.7.8:3000` to `192.168.1.10:3000` in the router configuration and now it will be accessible from the outer network on `5.6.7.8:3000`. Note that you can choose any free port, ports don’t have to match.). Of course it is only possible if you have the option to configure the router and you are willing to do so. (e.g.: if you are not in a café)
- You can use some tunneling tools like Ngrok or OpenSSH, which make a direct tunnel between the external machine and your server. This can also work if you don’t have the ability to change the router configuration.

Hope I was able to help. Good luck.

Comment: This was helpful, I ended up using ngrok which was very easy to set up.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that. :)